# Code for login with Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle

I have one oracle table `hrd_user` with data `user_name (rajesh )  pswd(12345)`.

I am  trying to login with this code but it show Not Registered User or Invalid Name/Password.

```
try
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Enter UserName and Password .");
        return;
    }

    cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM hrd_user where user_Name=:user_name and pswd=:pswd", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":user_name", textBox1.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":pswd", textBox2.Text));

    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        this.Hide();
        show_db_managoption frm = new show_db_managoption();
        frm.Show();
        ds.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not Registered User or Invalid Name/Password");
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Remove the colon from the bind: `OracleParameter("pswd" ...`

Answer (score 0):

though your code looks correct,i would like to suggest you few changes.

**1.**  Make sure your `OracleConnection` object `con` is opened using following statement.

```
con.Open();
```

**2.** make sure that there are no `whitespaces` in given `username` and `password`.
invoke `Trim()` method on both `username` and `password` to get rid of any whitespaces.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":user_name", textBox1.Text.Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":pswd", textBox2.Text.Trim()));
```

**3.** while comparing the username and password with `EmptyString` i would suggest you to use built-in method `String.IsNullOrWhitespace()` of String class to get better results.

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show(" Enter UserName and Password .");
    return;
}
```